# Extending the methods available to the Django User model via a proxy

Tags: python, django, proxy-classes

I'm integrating an app which in the past has had a custom user model to replace `auth.User` and added custom methods and relationships to other models.

I'd like to make it more of a reusable app, so I'm looking to add a proxy model to give the `User` the same methods so that things like `request.user.myfunc()` still work, and creating a `OneToOneField` relationship to the `User` for extra fields.

```
class ConsolesPermissionMixin(object):
    @property
    def is_admin(self):
        return self.is_superuser or self.is_staff

    _consoles = []

    @property
    def all_consoles(self):
        if not self._consoles:
            self._consoles = self.consoles.all()
        return self._consoles


class ProxyUser(ConsolesPermissionMixin, User):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True


class ConsoleUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    participant = models.OneToOneField(
        'consoles.Participant',
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )
    consoles = models.ManyToManyField(
        'consoles.Console',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
    objects = UserManager()

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'consoles'
        verbose_name = _('Console User')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Console Users')
```

So in order to implement this I've set `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'consoles.ProxyUser'` in settings. But this results in a `TypeError: ProxyUser cannot proxy the swapped model 'consoles.ProxyUser'.`

Surely for the proxy model to be used, it has to be set to `AUTH_USER_MODEL`, but in turn does that mean that `AUTH_USER_MODEL` can't be a proxy model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proxy models are used to modify Python behaviour of a model by extending a model class. Database tables aren't generated for proxy models. So you can't use a proxy model for `AUTH_USER_MODEL`. In fact, you can't use a proxy model if you want a db table for that model.

To understand proxy models better, consider this:

```
class Badge(models.Model):
    name = ...
    color = ... # gold/silver


class GoldBadge(Badge)
    class Meta:
        proxy = True

    def award(self, user):
        # award a gold badge to user

class SilverBadge(Badge):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True

    def award(self, user):
        # award a silver badge to user
```

Tables are generated for only `Badge` model whereas `GoldBadge` and `SilverBadge` are proxy models so no tables are generated for them. They are just extending the functionality (*i.e.* changing Python behaviour) of `Badge` model.

See docs on [proxy models](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/db/models/#proxy-models)

Comment: Thanks, I thought it'd still use the table defined by the inherited class while also picking up whatever else the proxy defined. Guess I need to rethink things & maybe migrate data from `auth.User` to this app.